# get web page source in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

i start developing in iOS and i have the next problem:

i need to extract the page source of web page to extract some data from it.

with some urls i'v succseed and some not

here is my code that i get the page source:

```
   (NSString *)getStringFromUrl:(NSString *)url{

    NSError *err = nil;  
    NSString *agentString = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_6; en-us) AppleWebKit/525.27.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.2.1 Safari/525.27.1";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                    [NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    [request setValue:agentString forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];


    NSData *data = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse: nil error: &err ];
    NSString *returnData = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [data bytes] length:[data length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if (err!=nil)
        NSLog(@"error message: %@",err.description);
    return returnData;
}
```

link that worked for me:

```
http://50.22.211.228:8000/played.html
```

link that not worked for me and return `nil` in `returnData`:

```
http://107.150.5.94:7070/played.html
```

Comment: Are you getting anything in the "err"? Also, why are sending in a NSString to the method, and not a NSURL (seeing as your method is called "getStringFromUrl")?

Comment: Did you verify the content encoding?

Comment: BTW - it wasn't me who down voted your question.

Comment: the err is staying nil
and the url is NSString but in alloc of request i create NSURL with it

Comment: You’re not actually passing `err` into any method that takes an `**error` parameter. And once you do, you should not rely on the error being populated. The Cocoa error handling convention is to check the return value of the method (`-[NSString initWithBytes…]` in this case), and only if it is `nil`, then check the error to see what happened. If the return value is not `nil`, the error is undefined.

Comment: i assign err in [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse: nil error: &err ]; and still err is nil. and tyt_g207 what do you mean by content encoding?

Comment: You should still not be checking `err` until you have determined that `returnData` is `nil`. If it is not `nil`, you should not look at the contents of `err` at all.

Comment: still in all my tests i received `nil` both in `err` and in `returnData`

Comment: Both URLs are returning a 404 error when I `curl` them. I don’t know why the first one works and the second doesn’t (and I was able to replicate the problem you are having), but it looks like something involving the headers or redirecting could be the culprit.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg If you look at these requests in Charles (or look at the `NSData` of the response), you'll see that the data is coming back fine. It's the conversion to a string that's failing. It's not a valid UTF8 string encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be that the second request is apparently not returning valid `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. If you look at the `NSData` itself (if you log that, you'll see the hexadecimal representation of the binary payload), you are receiving data, but it's the conversion to a `NSString` that is failing.

If you look at that page in a web browser, it gets confused, too (the characters don't make sense). I'd wager that they are not writing a valid UTF8 string in that HTML, though it's not immediately obvious what precisely they're doing (it doesn't appear to be a string encoding that I recognize).

You can use `NSASCIIStringEncoding` to see the same mess in your code that you'll see in your web browser.

Answer (score -1):

I use the following to get the source code of a web page as NSString:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"http://www.google.es"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
NSString *webSource = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

I hope this helps you and is what you are looking for.

Comment: i tried it and instead of nil i got in 'webSource' = "ICY 404 Resource Not Found
icy-notice1:<BR>SHOUTcast Distributed Network Audio Server/Linux v1.9.8<BR>
icy-notice2:The resource requested was not found<BR>" and error is nil